# How to change the order status with a custom order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

Hello i have this code which adds a custom status called refund issued to the order status

```
    function register_awaiting_shipment_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => 'Return',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Return <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Return <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )

        ) );
        register_post_status( 'wc-refund-issued', array(
            'label'                     => 'Refund Issued',
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Refund Issued<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Refund Issued <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )

            ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_awaiting_shipment_order_status' );
// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-awaiting-shipment'] = 'Return';
            $new_order_statuses['wc-refund-issued'] = 'Refund Issued';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses' );
```

i want to be able to change the custom order status through

```
$order->status_update('refund issued');
```

but it doens't work it only work for the status that already comes with woocommerce like processing and pending payment when i run the code it changes the status to payment pending instead of refund issued  what am i doing wrong ?  in the end what im trying to accomplish is to make a refund button in the view order area so the user can issue a refund request to the current order

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i was calling it wrong it supposed to be

```
$order->status_update('wc-refund-issued');
```

instead of

`$order->status_update('refund issued');`

Thank you very much